# Is it possible for fwrite to write some bytes but return zero?

Tags: c, glibc

According to the man page of `fwrite`:

> `fread()` and `fwrite()` return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number
>   of characters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return  value  is  a  short
>   item count (or zero).

I'm wondering if it possible for `fwrite(ptr, 65537, 1, fp)` to write only 512 bytes and yet return zero?

I tried to get a quick source trace to glibc-2.12.2 source code.

```
malloc/malloc.c:#define fwrite(buf, size, count, fp) _IO_fwrite (buf, size, count, fp)
```

I guess the real implementation is in the iofwrite.c.

```
_IO_size_t
_IO_fwrite (buf, size, count, fp)
     const void *buf;
     _IO_size_t size;
     _IO_size_t count;
     _IO_FILE *fp;
{
  _IO_size_t request = size * count;
  _IO_size_t written = 0;
  CHECK_FILE (fp, 0);
  if (request == 0)
    return 0;
  _IO_acquire_lock (fp);     
  if (_IO_vtable_offset (fp) != 0 || _IO_fwide (fp, -1) == -1)
    written = _IO_sputn (fp, (const char *) buf, request);
  _IO_release_lock (fp);
  /* We have written all of the input in case the return value indicates
     this or EOF is returned.  The latter is a special case where we
     simply did not manage to flush the buffer.  But the data is in the
     buffer and therefore written as far as fwrite is concerned.  */
  if (written == request || written == EOF)
    return count;
  else
    return written / size;
}
```

So, I guess it is possible return 0 in the return code of fwrite even if it has really written some bytes into the file.

Comment: Yes; if there is only space left on the disk for 512 bytes, then you have a short write, but 0 complete units of 65537 bytes (odd number; usually it would be 65536, wouldn't it?) were written, so the answer (return value) is 0.

Comment: If you want to know how much was really written, you should use `fwrite(ptr, 1, 65537, fp)` to get the exact byte count; now you'd get 512 back from your hypothetical short write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes — it is possible for `fwrite(ptr, 65537, 1, fp)` to return 0 as the return code even if it really wrote some bytes into the file.

For example, if there is only space left on the disk for 512 bytes, then you have a short write, but it wrote 0 complete units of 65537 bytes (that's a curious number; usually it would be 65536, wouldn't it?), so the return value must be 0.

If you want to know how much was really written, you should use:

```
 nbytes = fwrite(ptr, 1, 65537, fp);
```

to get the exact byte count; now you'd get 512 back from your hypothetical short write.